# Reading data from text file with missing values

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I want to read data from a file that has many missing values, as in this example:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,,,7,8
,,9,10,11
```

I am using the numpy.loadtxt function:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt('test.data', delimiter=',')
```

The problem is that the missing values break loadtxt (I get a *"ValueError: could not convert string to float:"*, no doubt because of the two or more consecutive delimiters).

Is there a way to do this automatically, with loadtxt or another function, or do I have to bite the bullet and parse each line manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd probably use [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#importing-data-with-genfromtxt):

```
>>> from numpy import genfromtxt
>>> genfromtxt("missing1.dat", delimiter=",")
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,  nan,  nan,   7.,   8.],
       [ nan,  nan,   9.,  10.,  11.]])
```

and then do whatever with the nans (change them to something, use a mask instead, etc.)  Some of this could be done inline:

```
>>> genfromtxt("missing1.dat", delimiter=",", filling_values=99)
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,  99.,  99.,   7.,   8.],
       [ 99.,  99.,   9.,  10.,  11.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the function expects to return a *numpy array* with all cells of the same type.

If you want a table with mixed strings and number, you should read it into a structured array instead, also you probably want to add `skip_header=1` to skip the first line, ie in your case something like:

```
np.genfromtxt('upeak_names.txt', delimiter="\t", dtype="S10,S10,f4,S10,f4,S10,f4", 
names=["id", "name", "Distance", "name2", "Distance2", "name3", "Distance3], skip_header=1)
```

See also:

- Documentation for genfromtxt:
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html
- Documentation for structured arrays in numpy:
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html